# Flask form super slow to load

Tags: python, flask

I have written a program getting user input from a flask form. But it takes ages for the form to load, when compared to a normal webpage. The status line at the bottom of the browser of the user's pc would show "waiting for response from "  for a handful of minutes with nothing on the screen whereas a web page served from the same server is loaded in a second. Can any body help with this?

The source is put in:

https://bitbucket.org/wailoktam/jobsearchdemo/src/master/hayateBig.py

line 268 - 307 is where the form is handled.

Many thanks. I have been scratching my head for days over this.

Comment: Have you done any modular debugging on your script already i.e. separating the Form loading from all the file readings that you do at the top of the script? Just want to be certain on the actual cause that is slowing the page down

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code?

Comment: I try the other part with an uploaded file (no flask form for user to input data) and the speed is fine. Just the form takes a handful of minutes to load. Any idea?